# Plane Equation From 3 Points Not Returning Correct Values

Tags: c++, math, raytracing, plane

As part of a raytracer experiment I'm working on in my high school classes, I need to make it so that I can get the 4 parts of a plane equation from 3 different points.  By 4 parts i mean in the equation Ax + By + Cz = D I need to find A, B, C, and D.  I understand the math behind this as its relatively simple vector math, but my code doesn't seem to work.

The function I use to construct the Plane object from the 3 points is as follows:

```
Plane::Plane(Vec3 A, Vec3 B, Vec3 C)
{
    //Getting both vectors
    Vec3 AB = B - A;
    Vec3 AC = C - A;

    //Cross Product
    Vec3 cr = AB.cross(AC);

    a = cr.getX();
    b = cr.getY();
    c = cr.getZ();
    d = a * A.getX() + b * B.getY() + c * C.getZ();
}
```

In this, Vec3 is just a vector class that holds (x, y, z), and the function names are pretty self explanatory (I hope).

An example of what it outputs:
If I put the vectors (-3, 0, 1), (2, 3, 0), and (0, 2, 3) into this, I get the following results

```
A = 8
B = -13
C = 1
D = -60
```

A, B, and C in this are correct, but D is not.

I'm not entirely certain what's wrong with the code, since it will sometimes get the output correctly on certain vectors, sometimes get parts correct, or sometimes get nothing correct at all, which leads me to believe there's a math mistake.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'll definitely have to figure out how to use a debugger; honestly, I didn't even really realize it was a thing.  Thanks for the help! Guess I still have a lot to learn before I can actually call myself good at programming.

Comment: You are using `A` and `a` to mean different things, then using `A` when you mean `a`. That isn't the cause of your error, but it's a very bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your example, you get the values for A, B, and C correct, the first place to look is in the calculation of D.

In your calculation of `d`, you use parts of three different vectors. This is not what the equation for `D` says to do. You want to use the three parts from *one* vector.

```
d = a * A.getX() + b * A.getY() + c * A.getZ();
```

This should work for any of the three vectors.

Comment: Thats definitely useful, but it doesn't solve the entire problem.  It's possible my question was poorly worded.  If I was to use a different set of vectors (the main one I've noticed this issue on is (-3, 0, 0), (0, 3, 0), (0, 0, 3)) then it will return completely A, B, and C, which makes D incorrect.  I'm not certain why.  Perhaps it's a problem with my vector class?

Comment: @NetherMan: What results do you get with that {A,B,C}? With pen and paper I get a=-9, b=9, c=9, d=27, which is correct.

Comment: @Beta you have no idea how disappointed in myself I am right now. Apparently, the calculator I've been using to calculate these numbers is incorrect, because that's the number I've been getting the whole time.  Which means that the two times I rewrote this entire portion, I've been doing it because of a faulty calculator.  Thanks.

Comment: Why not just express this line a `d = dot(cr, A)`?